# How can I locate the navigation element by text?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, javascript, protractor, jasmine

```
<li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>By Coordinator &amp; Salesman</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
    </li>
<li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>By Branch</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item active" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>Selling Branches</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
</li>
```

For the above code i need to click on the `span` items:

- click on 'Selling branch' and verify data is loaded and any error
- click on 'By Branches' and verify data is loaded without any error.

What is the best approach to write locator using protractor/js?

Answer (score 3):

Choosing the best, most reliable and readable locator is not always straightforward. Here, I would rely on the `nav-*` classes and use the [`by.cssContainingText` strategy](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText):

```
var sellingBranches = element(by.cssContainingText(".nav-item a.nav-link > span", "Selling Branches"));
sellingBranches.click();

var byBranch = element(by.cssContainingText(".nav-item a.nav-link > span", "By Branch"));
byBranch.click();
```

Note that, for better reusability and to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), it would probably be a good idea to define a function (or a *"Page Object" method* if following the concept) to select a navigation menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You can search by list (1) item position or its text (2); depend on your context, should the most stable.

1 -

```
li:nth-of-type(3) span
```

2 -

```
li span:contains('Selling Branches')
```

If you use jQuery, you would locate a element as in

```
$("li:nth-of-type(3) span")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `findElements` method by using `tagName` as `span`:

```
List<WebElement> l = obj.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
```

get your elements and take what you want.